# Advertising with iBeacon when app is in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I have been digging all forums and tutorials about transmitting in background mode with iBeacon. Until now, I couldn't find something solid which can help me. My app can successfully receive and transmit but when I press home button, transmitting stops and connection on other device/devices disappear. In myApp.plist, I added required keys but still nothing works. The question is, how can I make my app keep transmitting in background mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iBeacon will not advertise (transmit) in the background. If you need this you will not be able to use iBeacon and will instead need to implement your own BTLE advertisement (which will run in the background).

Comment: I created my own BTLE with referring that tutorial below;

[link](http://www.devfright.com/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-7-clbeaconregion-clbeacon/)

according to this tutorial, how can I perform tranmitting in bg? @Wain

Comment: You can't. You either use beacons and you can use region monitoring but not background. Or you use BTLE directly without beacons, no regions but background. You can't have all 3 at once...

Comment: @Wain can you suggest some reference links/articles for using BTLE directly without beacons, please.